# Using segment_sum with pmap in Jax

Tags: python, jax

I have the following function that I am trying to rewrite using `pmap` in Jax.

```
import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

X = np.random.randn(10,4)
index = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2])
alpha = np.ones(4)*0.1
lat = np.random.randn(10)
lon = np.random.randn(10)
num_unique = len(np.unique(index))

def fun(X,index,num_unique,alpha,lat,lon):
  weights = jnp.sum(X*alpha,axis=1)
  sum_weights = jax.ops.segment_sum(weights,index,num_segments = num_unique)
  lat = lat*weights
  lat = jax.ops.segment_sum(lat,index,num_segments=num_unique)/sum_weights
  lon = lon*weights
  lon = jax.ops.segment_sum(lon,index,num_segments=num_unique)/sum_weights
  return lat,lon

jit_fun = jax.jit(fun,static_argnums=2)
jit_fun(X,index,num_unique,alpha,lat,lon)
```

I first split up the arrays:

```
n_devices = 2
Xdiv = np.reshape(X,(n_devices,-1,X.shape[1]))
index_div = np.reshape(index,(n_devices,-1))
lat_div = np.reshape(lat,(n_devices,-1))
lon_div = np.reshape(lon,(n_devices,-1))

num_unique_div = np.zeros(n_devices)
for n in range(n_devices):
  num_unique_div[n] = len(np.unique(index_div[n,:]))
```

`num_unique_div` is now a 1d array with 2 elements that contains the number of unique IDs in each slice.

Then I try to use `pmap`:

```
pmap_fun = jax.pmap(jax.jit(fun,static_argnums=2),in_axes=(0,0,0,None,0,0))
pmap_fun(Xdiv,index_div,num_unique_div,alpha,lat_div,lon_div)
```

I get a ConcretizationTypeError. Is there a way to declare the offending `num_unique_div` as static, but still instruct pmap to map over its axis?

Comment: I have found factory methods an effective way to delineate static arguments (passed to the factory) and dynamic variables (arguments of the returned function which closes over the static arguments).
For this case however, I don't believe it's possible to simultaneously map over JAX arrays and concrete iterables. You could achieve a similar effect including a dynamic `id_devices` array and using `jnp.select` with a callable `condlist`.
The `sum_weights`  needs a `psum` which requires broadcasting the weights over the set of indices ([0,1,2]), undoing the sparse efficiency of `segment_sum`